# Drawing a nurbs curve along a surface

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, nurbs-surface

I think I've asked this question once before, but I am not sure if anyone out there has an answer.

My question is, is there away that I could draw a Nurbs Curve right along a surface?
As in the Nurbs Curb would fallow a certain shape.

For example, I am trying to re-create a a wire harness / Brake lines for a car, I have a reference scan of it, but I only have the A surface, the other side wasn't captured by the scanned.

[image]
I have tried using the poly tool, but it's too complicated and takes a lot of time.

I appreciate any answers you could share with me
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use Snapping.

- set Snapping to Face
- grab a curve point while holding Ctrl to temporarily enable the Snap to follow the shape of a target object

[image]

You can also take a look at Shrinkwrap modifier, but it can be little tricky for this kind of usage.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html

Comment: That helped so much :) thank you so so very much